# Data not being posted. Please review my code

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post the values as shown in the script from an HTML form.  I have confirmed that the form is successfully submitting the data. However, when I try to test the values being submitted using the `isset()` script, I get nothing at all.  I am also posting my function to see if I am making an error there.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }


        // require_once('mystuff/functions.php');

        echo $to_account = test_input($_POST['to_account']);
        echo $to_email = test_input($_POST['to_email']);
        echo $amount = test_input($_POST['amount']);
        echo $pin = test_input($_POST['pin']);



    } else {
        echo "Probably the data was not submitted";
    }



 <div class="container">
      <h2>Transfer:</h2>
      <form action="transCtrl.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="to_account">To Account</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_account" name="to_account" required pattern="[A-Z0-9]{13}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="to_email">To Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="to_email" name="to_email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" required min="100">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pin">8 Digit PIN</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{8}" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Let's see the form markup.

Comment: Why do you use `stripslashes()`?

Comment: You're testing for `$_POST['submit']` yet your submit button doesn't have a `name="submit"`. Why not simply test for `$_POST` itself? If you have a desktop browser you have [a lot of developer tools](https://www.lifewire.com/web-browser-developer-tools-3988965) at your disposal. Use them!

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you did not provide enough information for anyone to answer the question. Keep in mind that downvotes *are not personal*, only an indication of a question's thoroughness or usefulness. It doesn't matter 'who' did it.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead this

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Use this:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

You don't have a $_POST['submit'] variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to resolve the issue using your suggestion